# Equivalence classes and metric spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $S$ be the set of Cauchy sequences in $S$. Define "~" in $S$ by "$\{s_k\}$ ~ $\{t_k\}$" to mean that $d(s_k,t_k) \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$. Let $X'$ denote the set of equivalence classes of $S$ and let $s'$ denote the equivalence class of $s = \{s_k\}$.

I know $\phi(s',t') = \lim\limits_{k \to \infty} d(s_k,t_k)$ is a metric on $X'$.

Show $(X',\phi)$ is complete.

For $x \in X$, define $x'$ to be the equivalence class of the constant sequence ${x,x,...}$. Show that the function $x \to x'$ is an isometry of $X$ onto a dense subset of $X$.

If anyone can share a proof, or steer me in the right direction, maybe tell me what it is that I need to prove specifically, that would be great.

Comment: I don't understand. If we have two cauchy sequences $\{s_k\}$ and $\{t_k\}$, it does not necessarily mean that as $k \to \infty$, then $d(s_k,t_k)\to 0$. So the equivalence classes could be empty.

Comment: @TheLastCipher That would be fine. Actually, strictly speaking no equivalence class will be *empty,* since of course $\{s_k\} \sim \{s_k\}$ ;)

Comment: @RyleeLyman: Oh yes :))

Comment: @RyleeLyman: I think to show that $(X',\phi)$ is complete, we can simply pick a sequence-element for each equivalence class of sequences. This collection of sequences would be dense in $(X'\phi)$?

Comment: [proofwiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Completion_Theorem_(Metric_Space)) contains a complete proof.

Comment: @TheLastCipher Let's be careful: yes, it suffices to argue just by picking a representative for each equivalence class of sequences. but! This is because two sequences $x'$ and $y'$ represent the same point in $X'$ exactly when $\phi(x',y') = 0$, *not* because they form a dense set. In fact, (the equivalence classes of) the sequences we chose form *all* of $X'$!

Comment: @RyleeLyman: +1..Okay. This is then due to the fact that isometry preserves completeness? https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Metric_Space_Completeness_is_Preserved_by_Isometry

Comment: Not at all! This is why I preferred the term "isometric embedding": The map $x \mapsto x'$ is usually **very far** from being surjective. As an example, $\sqrt{2}$ is not an element of $\mathbb Q$ (with the metric being the standard metric on $\mathbb R$ restricted to $\mathbb Q$), but the sequence of decimal approximations to $\sqrt{2}$ is a Cauchy sequence that is not equivalent to any constant sequence coming from $\mathbb Q$

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you've defined $\phi$, but it *ought* to be something like $\phi(\{x_k\},\{y_\ell\}) := \lim_{k\to\infty} d(x_k,y_k)$.

I think firstly you need to check that this is well-defined and a metric on $X'$ (i.e. for $a,b,c \in X'$, $\phi(a,b) = \phi(b,a)$, $\phi(a,b) = 0 \implies a = b$, and the triangle inequality $\phi(a,b) \le \phi(a,c) + \phi(c,b)$)

Completeness means "Cauchy sequences converge", i.e. if $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence in $X'$ (note: a sequence of equivalence classes of sequences!) that is Cauchy, then there exists $a \in X'$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \phi(a_n,a) = 0$ (I think something like the "diagonal" sequence $\{a_{n,n}\}$, that is the sequence with $n$th term equal to the $n$th of $a_n$, should work).

To show that the map $x \mapsto x'$ is an isometry (I would prefer to say an isometric embedding) means we need to check that it satisfies $\phi(x',y') = d(x,y)$. If my definition of $\phi$ is right this should be a one-line proof.

Finally we want to show that the image of the map is dense, that is, given any element $x \in X'$ and any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a constant sequence $y' = y,y,\dots$ such that $\phi(x,y') < \epsilon$. This should follow pretty straightforwardly from the fact that $x$ (as a sequence in $X$) is Cauchy.